# Pass text value to another component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

How to pass text value to another component using Redux in React?

I am learning Redux in React. I am trying to pass text value to another component using Redux in React.

My code is like below

**Mycomponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Mycomponent extends Component {
    state = {
        textInput: '',
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.props.dispatch({ type: "add" });
    }

    render = () => {        
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ nameState: state.nameState});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Mycomponent);
```

**nameAction.js**

```
export const nameAction = () => ({
    type: 'add'
});

export default { nameAction };
```

**nameReducer.js**

```
const nameReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'add': {
            return {
                ...state,
                nameState: action.payload
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default nameReducer;
```

**Outputcomponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Outputcomponent extends Component {
    render = (props) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>{this.props.nameState }</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Outputcomponent;
```

Comment: Side note: Dont you also have to pass a payload to your dispatch in your onChange?

Comment: You didn't pass anything to dispatch and in the action itself

Comment: Thanks @Kevin.a. I am new to Redux. How can I do that ? Could you please guide me in this regard ?

Comment: Thanks @DennisVash. I am new to Redux. How to pass anything to dispatch and in the action ?  Could you please guide me in this regard ?

Comment: this.props.dispatch({ type: "add"  , payload : "Some value here"}); @abuabu

Comment: Thanks @Kevin.a. I am storing value in `State`. How can I pass value from `State` to "Some value here" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The use of redux hooks explained by Josiah is for me the best approach but you can also use mapDispatchToProps.

**Even if the main problem is that you don't pass any data in your 'add' action.**

#### nameAction.js

> You call the action.payload in **nameReducer.js** but it does not appear in your action

```
export const nameAction = (text) => ({
  type: 'add',
  payload: text
});
```

#### Mycomponent.js

> Then as for your state we can mapDispatchToProps.

*(I think it's better to trigger the action with a submit button and save the input change in your textInput state, but I guess it's intentional that there is none)*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {nameAction} from './nameAction'

class Mycomponent extends Component {
    state = {
        textInput: '',
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.props.nameAction(event.target.value);
    }

    render = () => {        
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ nameState: state.nameState});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ nameAction: (text) => dispatch(nameAction(text))});

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Mycomponent);
```

#### OutputComponent.js

> to get the data two possibilities either with a class using connect and mapStateToProps , or using the useSelector hook with a functional component.

**with a Class**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class OutputComponent extends Component {
    render = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>{this.props.nameState}</div>
            </div>
        );
    };
}

const mapStateToProps = state => state;

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(OutputComponent);
```

**with a functional component**

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const OutputComponent = () => {
    const nameState = useSelector((state) => state.nameState);
    return (
        <div>
            <div>{nameState}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default OutputComponent;
```

**Of course you must not forget to create a strore and to provide it to the highest component**

#### store.js

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import nameReducer from "./nameReducer";

const store = createStore(nameReducer);

export default store;
```

#### index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";

ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Daphaz for your reply. How can I receive Redux value at destination component ? I am using this code `import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Outputcomponent extends Component {
    render = (props) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>{this.props.nameState }</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Outputcomponent;`

Comment: hi @abuabu i edit the answer for receive value

Comment: Thanks @Daphaz. I am getting this error `mapStateToProps() in Connect(OutputComponent) must return a plain object. Instead received undefined.`

Comment: hi @abuabu i edit i made a mistake in OutputComponent is "const mapStateToProps = state => state;"

Comment: Thanks @Daphaz. May be you didn't make any edit. Could you please run your whole code in your machine ? Actually I am not getting any output and any error also.  I am not so expert in React Redux to debug the whole situation. I want to write something in `Text box` of  `Mycomponent` and it'll appear in `OutputComponent`. Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu it's work for me see on sandbox is the same code [SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/xz9oh)

Comment: Thanks @Daphaz. Yes, your sandbox solution is working. But my one is not working. I am trying to send values from `Child` component to `Parent` component. Thanks

Comment: I removed `App.js` file and moved everything to `index.js` file. Can it create any issue ?

Answer (score 1):

## Component

```js
const AddTodo = () => {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  const handleChange = (e) => setTodo(e.target.value);
  const handleSubmit = (e)  => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(addTodoAction(todo));
  } 

  return {
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
    </form>
  }
)
```

## Actions

```js
const addTodoAction = (text) => {
   dispatch({
    type: "ADD_TODO",
    payload: text
   })
}
```

## Reducers

```
const addTodoReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "ADD_TODO":
      return {
        todo: action.payload,
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

## store

```
 // some code for store.js
```

## Accessing this todo from another component

```js
  const ComponentA = () => {
    const {todo} = useSelector(state => state.todo);

   return (
     <p> {todo} </p>
   )
  }
```

Side Note:

- Redux comes with too much boilerplate if you want to pass text from one component to another, just use `props`